# how to apply svm on a balanced dataset

Tags: r, svm

I want to attempt to use Support Vector Machines (SVMs) on my dataset. the dataset i am using was extremely unbalanced and I was warned that SVMs dont perform well on extremely unbalanced data.

```
table(df4$Price)

     0      1 
100020   1249
```

therefor i balanced a dataset using different techniques such as oversampling undersampling and ROSE.

```
data.rose <- ROSE(Price~., data=df4, seed=3, N = 200040)$data
table(data.rose$Price)

     0      1 
 99960 100080 
data.balanced.over <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = df4, method = "over",N = 200040)$data
table(data.balanced.over$Price)

     0      1 
100020 100020
```

i want to know how to apply svm on this balanced dataset??